# MVC4 anchor in a anchor razor render fail

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, anchor, razor-2

I have problem with razor render engine that thoes not render a anchor tag in a anchor tag right.

Code:

```
@if (Model.Schedules != null){
   foreach(var schedule in Model.Schedules){
       <a class="module-item">
           <a>Hello</a>
       </a>
   }
}
```

**This is what the razor engine should render:**

```
  <a class="module-item"> <a>Hello<a/> </a>
  <a class="module-item"> <a>Hello<a/> </a>
```

**but instead razor engine render:**

```
<a class="module-item"><a/>
<a>Hello</a>
<a class="module-item"><a/>
<a>Hello</a>
```

And i did test to change the first anchor tag to a another tag and then it works fine.
is there any hack/way around this?

Update:
My misson was to replace my option --> li --> a with something else and

```
<a>
  <div>
    <a></a>
  </div>
</a>
```

does not work in mvc4 so my solution was this:

```
<div>
  <a></a>
  <div>
    <a>/<a>
  </div>
</div>
```

It is strange that you not can do a anchor tag in a anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the `<a>` in to `</a>`  as closing tag.
Change your code into this and have a try

```
 @if (Model.Schedules != null){
   foreach(var schedule in Model.Schedules){
       <a class="module-item">
           <a>Hello</a>
       </a>
   }
}
```

Hope it will solve your isssue

Comment: sorry but i missed to write out corrent end tag here. Of course there should be an end tag there.